# Blueimp Jquery File Upload S3 & Resize

Tags: php, jquery, amazon-s3, imagick, blueimp

I am using the [Blueimp/jQuery-File-Uploader](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) and the Amazon S3 plugin that is available for it and all is working out fine however I need to resize my images to be no more or less that 640px on the shortest side.

my current code is

```
   global $s3;
    if (isset($_REQUEST['_method']) && $_REQUEST['_method'] === 'DELETE') {
        return "";
    }
    $upload = isset($_FILES['files']) ? $_FILES['files'] : null;
    $info = array();
    if ($upload && is_array($upload['tmp_name'])) {
        foreach($upload['tmp_name'] as $index => $value) {
            $fileTempName = $upload['tmp_name'][$index];

            $file_name = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME'] : $upload['name'][$index]);
            $extension=end(explode(".", $file_name));
            $rand = rand(1,100000000);
            $sha1 = sha1($rand);
            $md5 = md5($sha1);
            $filename = substr($md5, 0, 8);
            $fileName=$filename.".".$extension;    

            $fileName = $prefix.str_replace(" ", "_", $fileName);
            $response = $s3->create_object($bucket, $fileName, array('fileUpload' => $fileTempName, 'acl' => AmazonS3::ACL_PUBLIC, 'meta' => array('keywords' => 'example, test'),));
            if ($response->isOK()) {
                $info[] = getFileInfo($bucket, $fileName);
            } else {
                //     echo "<strong>Something went wrong while uploading your file... sorry.</strong>";

            }
        }
```

And I have written this bit of PHP however I am not sure as to how I can get the two working together.

```
$image = new Imagick('test2.jpg');
$imageprops = $image->getImageGeometry();

$w=$imageprops['width'];
$h=$imageprops['height'];
$edge = min($w,$h);
$ratio = $edge / 640;

$tWidth = ceil($w / $ratio);
$tHeight = ceil($h / $ratio);

if ($imageprops['width'] <= 640 && $imageprops['height'] <= 640) {
    // don't upscale
} else {
    $image->resizeImage($tWidth,$tHeight,imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 0.9, true);
}
$image->writeImage("test2-resized.jpg");
```

any help will be gratefully received, thanks

Comment: Is all of the code above tested and working?

Comment: yes separately it is all fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is based on the assumption that all code in the OP's message was correct, and simply re-arranged it as requested.

**Update**: four upvotes (so far) seems to indicate the OP was correct not only regarding the code, but also regarding the magnitude of the issue. I do OSS as a matter of course, so by all means, let me know explicitly if this is of any interest to you so we can improve on this on github (any action is fine -- upvote the question, upvote the answer, post a comment, or any combination thereof).

```
function resize($imgName, $srcName)
{
    $image = new Imagick($imgName);
    $imageprops = $image->getImageGeometry();

    $w=$imageprops['width'];
    $h=$imageprops['height'];
    $edge = min($w,$h);
    $ratio = $edge / 640;

    $tWidth = ceil($w / $ratio);
    $tHeight = ceil($h / $ratio);

    if ($imageprops['width'] <= 640 && $imageprops['height'] <= 640) {
        return $imgName;
    } else {
        $image->resizeImage($tWidth,$tHeight,imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 0.9, true);
    }
    $extension=end(explode(".", $srcName));
    // Change "/tmp" if you're running this on Windows
    $tmpName=tempnam("/tmp", "resizer_").".".$extension;
    $image->writeImage($tmpName);
    return $tmpName
}

global $s3;
if (isset($_REQUEST['_method']) && $_REQUEST['_method'] === 'DELETE') {
    return "";
}
$upload = isset($_FILES['files']) ? $_FILES['files'] : null;
$info = array();
if ($upload && is_array($upload['tmp_name'])) {
    foreach($upload['tmp_name'] as $index => $value) {
        $file_name = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME'] : $upload['name'][$index]);
        $fileTempName = resize($upload['tmp_name'][$index], $file_name);
        $extension=end(explode(".", $file_name));
        $rand = rand(1,100000000);
        $sha1 = sha1($rand);
        $md5 = md5($sha1);
        $filename = substr($md5, 0, 8);
        $fileName=$filename.".".$extension;    

        $fileName = $prefix.str_replace(" ", "_", $fileName);
        $response = $s3->create_object($bucket, $fileName, array('fileUpload' => $fileTempName, 'acl' => AmazonS3::ACL_PUBLIC, 'meta' => array('keywords' => 'example, test'),));
        if ($response->isOK()) {
            $info[] = getFileInfo($bucket, $fileName);
        } else {
            //     `echo "<strong>Something went wrong while uploading your file... sorry.</strong>";`

        }
        unlink($fileTempName);
}
```

Comment: looks good but i get an error can I post my file somewhere for you to check?

Comment: I have posted the code @ http://codepad.viper-7.com/NQQYwd could you let me know if this is ok?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, the "<" signs were confusing StackOverflow's parser... Please try it again now. Actually, I think I'm using the wrong tag when posting code -- I tried looking at the documentation yesterday but I came up empty... I use <pre>, which is probably not the best way to go.

Comment: @JustinErswell: ok, I think I figured it out now. :)

Comment: cool beans playing with it I seem to have gotten this error now   PHP Fatal error:Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'unable to open image `/tmp/resizer_sSs8jZ./tmp/phphnKgi9':  @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2587' in /var/www/portal/imgup/awssdk.php:65\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/portal/imgup/awssdk.php(65): Imagick->writeimage('/tmp/resizer_sS...')\n#1 /var/www/portal/imgup/awssdk.php(78): resize('/tmp/phphnKgi9')\n#2 /var/www/portal/imgup/index.php(46): uploadFiles('cdmwl2012', 'FR24010/5093a01...', '59')\n#3 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/portal/imgup/awssdk.php on line 65

Comment: indeed re errors however re photo i thought i was I will go back and check the code

Comment: @Justin, yes, I realized there was a problem with the proof of concept itself. :) Check it out now.

Comment: last error i promise ;) PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be passed by reference in /awssdk.php on line 81

Comment: @Justing: that ain't mine! :)

Comment: Great, I'm glad it works for you. Unfortunately there doesn't really seem to be any elegant solution for integrating this code into the jQuery plugin, because the PHP back-end seems way too basic to support such optional image manipulation. A complete OOP rewrite would be needed for this to make any sense.

Comment: the support in this plugin isn't great I have been struggling with this for a while now, and I have just hit more issues can you suggest a method for doing this better?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18982/discussion-between-gutza-and-justin-erswell)